# Not able to upload image to the server in android

Tags: php, android, image, upload

I have used some code from the internet for uploading image

```
public class ActUpload extends Activity {
InputStream is;
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.blue);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new
ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
try{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new
HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:80/php/base.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
}
}
```

and even took some php code copied some php code which i am running in local sever using wamp server. There is no response in the local server.
and this is my php code.

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
echo $base;
// base64 encoded utf-8 string
$binary=base64_decode($base);
// binary, utf-8 bytes
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
// print($binary);
//$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);
$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo '<img src=test.jpg>';
?>
```

Can any one help me in this. thanks in advance.

Comment: from where you get this PHP code ?

Comment: I got the code from the same link where i got the java code. i had just copied it.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 on a TCP stack is the loopback address. Your android device is trying to post to itself, not to your wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

A nice tutorial for uploading image to server-

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/

**Edit:**

You just need to change this according to your local server:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://<local ip address>/android/upload_image.php");

// For example,in my code,i used:
// HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.100.47/android/upload_image.php");
```

Comment: i have followed the tutorial and change it according as i need and given http://127.0.0.1:80/Upload_image_ANDROID/upload_image.php as per my local system server but am not getting the result. Can you tell me any suggestion for that.

Comment: @user973049: When i used this code,it was working fine in my local server.are you getting any error or so?Can you show me more of your code?

Comment: @user973049: I think,you have made a mistake in your code... 127.0.0.1:80,why so??

Comment: @user973049, Run your wamp server. click wamp icon then localhost and tell use what URL come in your browser's address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to solve the problem? I did get it to work when i changed $base=$_REQUEST['image']; => $base=$_POST['image']; and commented out the following line header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); Btw, did try to convert the code to use HttpURLConnection api?